# How to run code only when i click on a button..python/wxpython/boa constructor

Tags: python, wxpython, boa-constructor

I'm developing a GUI using wxPython (Boa Constructor IDE). My GUI has the following:

1. Rich text control
2. Start button
3. Stop Button

My requirement is that when I press the START button, numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.) should start printing in the text control; it should stop when I press the STOP button. Code and GUI are as shown. What changes do I need to make to meet my requirements?

**Appearance:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import wx
import wx.richtext

def create(parent):
    return Frame3(parent)

[wxID_FRAME3, wxID_FRAME3BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME3BUTTON2, wxID_FRAME3PANEL1, 
 wxID_FRAME3RICHTEXTCTRL1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(5)]

class Frame3(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME3, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(579, 234), size=wx.Size(414, 492),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame3')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(406, 458))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME3PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(406, 458),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.richTextCtrl1 = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(id=wxID_FRAME3RICHTEXTCTRL1,
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(96, 96), size=wx.Size(200, 100),
              style=wx.richtext.RE_MULTILINE, value=u'')
        self.richTextCtrl1.SetLabel(u'richText')

        self.button2 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME3BUTTON2, label=u'STOP',
              name='button2', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(256, 280),
              size=wx.Size(75, 23), style=0)
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME3BUTTON2)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME3BUTTON1, label=u'START',
              name='button1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(88, 280),
              size=wx.Size(75, 23), style=0)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME3BUTTON1)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def OnButton1Button(self, event):  #START BUTTON
        event.Skip()

    def OnButton2Button(self, event):  #STOP BUTTON
        event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Please cut your image down to size so that it doesn't have all that white in it.

Comment: Your code indentation is all wrong here. I presume it's not really?

Comment: @chris...the indentation is perfect...and image upload stack overflow is not allowing me to upload for freshers..ill try to upload again

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I edited..check now

Comment: For a moment I was like, boa constrictor?

Comment: @AbhranilDas why...whats wrong with boa?

Comment: I wonder why this is getting downvoted. Clearly you didn't do much research, but the question itself is pretty sensible and well documented.

Comment: The problem is not exactly as i asked...i need to use similar GUI event in my project...i made the Q simple ,so that it can be easily understood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

In general, this is an accepted way of doing it in wxPython, and comes straight from [the docs](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks)

1. Create a new "data" event.
2. Make your controller listen for the "data" events
3. Let pressing the "Start" button start a thread that increments a counter and sends a "data" event to your window with the counter value attached.
4. Upon reception of the event, add the value to your `RichTextCtrl`

### Example

Here's an example. Note in particular the use of `Connect()` to listen for incoming value events.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext
import threading
import time


EVT_ID_VALUE = wx.NewId()

class DataEvent(wx.PyEvent):
  def __init__(self, data):
    wx.PyEvent.__init__(self)
    self.SetEventType(EVT_ID_VALUE)
    self.data=data


class Frame3(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    self.counter = 0
    self.worker = None

    wx.Frame.__init__(
      self, name='', 
      parent=parent,
      pos=wx.Point(579, 234), 
      size=wx.Size(414, 492),
      style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame3'
    )
    self.panel1 = wx.Panel(
      name='panel1', 
      parent=self,
      pos=wx.Point(0, 0), 
      size=wx.Size(406, 458),
      style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL
    )
    self.richTextCtrl1 = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(
      parent=self.panel1, 
      pos=wx.Point(96, 96), 
      size=wx.Size(200, 100),
      style=wx.richtext.RE_MULTILINE, 
      value=u''
    )
    self.richTextCtrl1.SetLabel(u'richText')
    self.richTextCtrl1.SetScrollbars(20,20,50,50)
    self.button2 = wx.Button(
      label=u'STOP',
      name='button2', 
      parent=self.panel1, 
      pos=wx.Point(256, 280),
      size=wx.Size(75, 23), 
      style=0
    )
    self.button2.Bind(
      wx.EVT_BUTTON, 
      self.OnStop
    )
    self.button1 = wx.Button(
      label=u'START',
      name='button1', 
      parent=self.panel1, 
      pos=wx.Point(88, 280),
      size=wx.Size(75, 23), 
      style=0
    )
    self.button1.Bind(
      wx.EVT_BUTTON, 
      self.OnStart
    )
    self.Connect(-1, -1, EVT_ID_VALUE, self.OnValue )

  def OnValue(self, event):
    self.richTextCtrl1.AppendText("%d\n"%event.data)
    
  
  def OnStart(self, event):  #START BUTTON
    self.richTextCtrl1.AppendText("START\n")
    if not self.worker:
      self.worker = WorkerThread(self)
      self.worker.start() 

  def OnStop(self, event):  #STOP BUTTON
    self.richTextCtrl1.AppendText("STOP\n")
    if self.worker:
      self.worker.stop() 


class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, notify_window):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.counter = 0
    self._notify_window = notify_window
    self.abort = False 

  def run(self):
    while not self.abort:
      self.counter += 1
      wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, DataEvent(self.counter))
      time.sleep(1)

  def stop(self):
      self.abort = True



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame3(None, "My Hello App")
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @BharathSharma Glad it helped! Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark if it solved your problem. Good luck with the rest of your work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple as this, I would just use a wx.Timer instead of messing with threads. like in [this tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/).

If you really want to use threads, then you'll probably want to read one of the following:

- [Long running tasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks)
- [Non-Blocking GUI](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui)
- [WxPython and threads](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/)